# Common base bias reduces input impedance

Tags: transistors, biasing

[image]When biasing the common base as shown I was expecting the input impedance to be (1/gm1 + R3/Beta)//(R1//Rpi2). So we with Beta of 100, and biasing current of 250 uA I was expecting the impedance to be around 100+50 (ignoring R1 and Rpi2). But when I simulate the circuit it is coming up to be < 2 Ohms.  Could someone please help me understand why?

I

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzqy2q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your circuit is an amplifier (Q2) with high open-loop voltage gain and strong negative feedback back (via Q1) back to its input: -

[image]

This means that the input impedance will be very low because it now behaves like a virtual ground (as per classic op-amp theory). None of these transistors are in common-base by the way.

Comment: Initially I was tying to create a common base topology with Q1, and installed Q2 for biasing purposes to generate a constant current across R1 with diode drop.  It seems the circuit behavior different now.  Could you please further explain the virtual ground, I am assuming that I am connecting to ground through Rpi2.  Further explanation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Link to virtual ground](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/understanding-the-virtual-short-in-op-amp-circuits/). Regards this: *I am assuming that I am connecting to ground through Rpi2* - I have no idea what this means @electronicah

Comment: I am talking about the small signal model of both transistors, Doing KCL on Q1 emitter, shows  impedance as follows 1) R1  2) Rpi of Q2 3) re of Q1+ reflected R3 into the emitter.  all should be in parallel.  Is my understanding is correct or  not.

Comment: @electronicah did you forget something in your comment? Anyway, you can do KCL to your hearts content but it still won't alter the fact the the input is connected to a virtual earth and that has theoretically zero ohms input impedance. The emitter follower formed by Q1 will have an output impedance (at the emitter) of only a few tens of ohms so, I'm not sure what else you might expect.

Comment: I do understand that it will be virtual ground, but I am trying to understand the reason why?  actually simulation supports your opinion.  I just did not see the feedback in my analysis and trying to understand how can I correlate small signal analysis "KCL" to the feedback loop.

Comment: Q1 is an emitter follower hence any voltage on its base will be 99% transferred to its emitter hence, virtually 100% negative feedback.

Comment: Thanks for feedback.

Comment: @electronicah [what to do next for completing this question and answer session](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: I think I got what I need for now, I will need to go back and check math model to derive different loop gains.

Comment: @electronicah not quite so fast, this Q and A should be closed down so, you need to consider accepting my answer. The link shows you how to do it but, if you want the simple version [try this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png)